# AppEngine for Android can't find/run appcfg.py script on Windows

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine

I try to make this sample from google
https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial
And I stoped on the step **Upload Places Simulated Data**. Maybe someone made this sample and can help me with finding appconfig.py

I tried to run appcfg.cmd with upload_data action from command line. And I received this error:

> "Bad argument: Expected an action: [update, request_logs, rollback, update_indexes, update_cron, update_dispatch, update_dos, update_queues, cron_info, vacuum_indexes, help, download_app, version, set_default_version, resource_limits_info, start, stop, backends list, backends rollback, backends update, backends start, backends stop, backends delete, backends configure, backends]usage: AppCfg [options]  [] []"

Any ideas? Thank you for helping.